# NixOS - Second Monitor freezes after sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, freeze, gpu, nvidia, nixos

I currently have the problem that my second monitor connected to my RazerBlade 15 freezes on NixOS 23.05 after sleep. The second monitor is connected via an dock. I am not entirely sure how to fix but from what I see from journalctl it seems to be related to the nvidia gpu. This is the last error I get before the system crashes

> nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Failed to query display engine channel state: 0x0000c67e:6:0:0x0000000f

The error is logged out about three dozen times with different addresses. Would be great if somebody had an idea how I could fix this

Comment: Can you provide your nixos config? That would help debug. Also, if you haven't checked this already: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nvidia#Fix_graphical_corruption_on_suspend.2Fresume